# Fixed or random effects for pooling groups from the same survival analysis

Tags: survival, meta-analysis, pooling

I want to analyze published survival analysis but some of the paper report 3 groups and I'm interested in pooling the two groups with poorer prognosis and compare them to the group with better one.

I was thinking to use a meta-analytical approach and use a generic inverse variance approach between the two groups with poor prognosis using the best one as a reference.

Should I pool them using a fixed or random effects model?

Comment: In what way would you use a "random effects model" to pool the 2 groups? Do you have access to the individual observations, or just to the summaries for each group?

Comment: I have access to the summary hazard ratio and confidence interval of the 2 groups compared to the reference one, so I can calculate an effect size and a standard error and compute a summary measure of the two groups as it was a "mini" meta-analysis of 2 studies https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_convert_a_hazard_ratio_for_3_different_categories_to_a_hazard_ratio_for_2_different_categories

Comment: Use both methods and see if they are consistent. If they are not, then probably your findings will mainly be hypothesis generating